# Identification of a live action A Christmas Carol based on a courthouse nativity scene, ends with a debate with a priest and Scrooge buried alive

Tags: story-identification, a-christmas-carol

I'm trying to track down a live action retelling of A Christmas Carol I would have seen on TV sometime around the early to mid 2000's in the United States. It was a standalone movie with frequent commercial breaks. It felt like it was made-for-TV but I can't say for sure.

The main deviation I remember is that the main plot is Scrooge petitioning to remove a nativity scene from in front of the courthouse. I can't remember if he gets permission or not but the scene ends with Scrooge going outside and personally busting up the display.

I don't remember the three ghosts, so I don't remember if they were cut or if I just missed them, but I do remember Scrooge losing a debate with a holy, priestly figure. Scrooge would say some kind of secular fallacy, and then the priest would rationally explain how Scrooge was wrong. The entire movie was very pro-religion, not sure of the exact denomination.

Then the last thing I remember is Scrooge was alive in a closed casket and begging to be let out while Marley's ghost looked over him. I don't remember the ending.

Comment: Take a look at https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/ae2ga/tomt_version_of_christmas_carol_scrooges_coffin/ (several titles listed)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like it may be *Scrooge and Marley* from 2001, described on [p. 88 of *The Christmas Encyclopedia, Third Edition*](https://books.google.com/books?id=MdGoAAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA88&pg=PA88):

> Made-for-television Christian evangelical adaptation, starring Dean Jones as Scrooge. Hating Christmas and outraged at seeing a Nativity scene outside City Hall, Scrooge launches a lawsuit to have the offending display removed. The resulting court case brings on the noted pastor, Dr. D. James Kennedy (portraying himself), now-late president of Coral Ridge Ministries, as an expert witness, who presents crucial evidence for Christ's transformational impact on the world. Based on the book *What If Jesus Had Never Been Born?* by D. James Kennedy. Narrated by Joan Plowright. Written and directed by Fred Holmes. Produced by Sergein Davidoff, Fred Holmes, and Cathy King. Coral Ridge Ministries. Available on VHS from Coral Ridge Ministries. 48 min.

It's available in full on YouTube:

You can see the scene of Scrooge getting mad about the nativity scene at 4 minutes 25 seconds in, a scene with the nativity getting dismantled while Scrooge gloats at 23 minutes 11 seconds, the debate with D. James Kennedy around 31-41 minutes in, and the scene with Scrooge stuck in a coffin starting at 45 minutes 40 seconds in.